# Calculate % increase C# ConsoleApp

Tags: c#

I tried finding this question somewhere but I couldn't quite understand or find what I wanted.

I want to make a console app in C# that calculates the increase/decrease of numbers you put in.

Console.WriteLine("Value 2 days ago:");
int day2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

```
Console.WriteLine("Value 3 days ago:");
int day3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

How can I make the app print the % change in the 2 numbers?

Comment: Well firstly do you know the mathematical formula you need to use? If so, then making it so maths on the variables is easy. Assign the result of that to a new variable and then write it to the console.

Comment: `(day3 - day2) / day2 * 100` See [here](https://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/percent-change.html).

Comment: @RobertHarvey It doesn't work. It says the difference between them is 0%.

Comment: Check your types.  You're probably doing integer arithmetic.  Try casting the denominator to a `double`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am sorry, I started programming 6 days ago, I don't really know what any of that means. Would you mind giving me a simple explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TBH, This is not really a C# Question, but more of a math question.

`change = (new_val - old_val) / old_val;`

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Value 2 days ago:");
int day2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Value 3 days ago:");
int day3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine($"T-2day had {(100*(day2-day3))/(double)day2} % change from T-3day");
```

> cast to `(double)` is done so we won't encounter integer arithmetics which would round our solution, if you need only whole percent, you can neglect the cast!
> didn't test in console, have fun

Comment: Hey thanks. I see this works sometimes, but when I do this with, 500 and 100 it says it's only a 80% increase. Why is that?